# threejs GLTF model is streched?

Tags: three.js, textures, blender, gltf

I have an issue with streched model, nothing seems to help and I didn't tinker with the model, mine looks like this:

[image]

while it really should be looking like this (from blender):

[image]

or like this (from gltf viewer):
[image]

I think something is making my GLTF model strech a little bit, and so it looks odd, what could cause it?

Comment: It sounds like your code may be choosing the wrong camera aspect ratio for your viewport size. You'd need to share your code to get help on this, if so.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy seems like you were right, it was the aspect ratio, all I need is to play with it and adjust it to my window resize function. thank you!